# Unable to INSERT data from form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I have been working on this process for the past two days and might be missing something very obvious, so I am hoping for some extra eyes to spot the issue.

My form is passing the fields and I am able to connect to my database and echo out both the $_POST data (var_dump($_POST)) and also echo out the variables successfully.  I get my connection message at line 35, but the script does not proceed to the SQL INSERT section.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php
session_start();
    //Get user id for posting to record
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    
        //Get posted data and sanitize
        $custId = filter_var($_POST['cust_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $name = filter_var($_POST['_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $ordDate = filter_var($_POST['ordDate'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $reqDate = filter_var($_POST['reqDate'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bAddr = filter_var($_POST['_baddr'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bCont = filter_var($_POST['_contact'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bEmail = filter_var($_POST['_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bFax = filter_var($_POST['_fax'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bMobile = filter_var($_POST['_mobile'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bPhone = filter_var($_POST['_phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $dAddr = filter_var($_POST['_daddr'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $dCont = filter_var($_POST['_dContact'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bEmail = filter_var($_POST['_dEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bMobile = filter_var($_POST['_dMobile'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bPhone = filter_var($_POST['_dPhone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $notes = filter_var($_POST['_delNotes'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "edwardm3_generation"; 
    $username = "edwardm3_gen";
    $password = "*********";
    $sql = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;";
    $dsn_Options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
    // 
    // Create a new connection to the MySQL database using PDO, $my_Db_Connection is an object
    try { 
      $my_Db_Connection = new PDO($sql, $username, $password, $dsn_Options);
      echo "Connected successfully";
               } catch (PDOException $error) {
      echo 'Connection error: ' . $error->getMessage();
    }
    
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (custId, orderDate, reqDate, bAddr, bCont, bFax, bMobile, bPhone, dAddr, dCont, dEmail, dMobile, dPhone, notes, orderedBy) VALUES (:custId, :ordDate, :reqDate, :bAddr, :bCont, :bFax, :bMobile, :bPhone, :dAddr, :dCont, :dEmail, :dMobile, :dPhone, :notes, :id)";
       
    $stmt = $my_Db_Connection->prepare($sql2);
    
    $stmt ->bindParam(':custId', $custId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':ordDate', $ordDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':reqDate', $reqDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':bAddr', $bAddr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':bCont', $bCont, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':bFax', $bFax, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':bMobile', $bMobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':bPhone', $bPhone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':dAddr', $dAddr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':dCont', $dCont, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':dEmail', $dEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':dMobile', $dMobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':dPhone', $dPhone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':notes', $notes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':create', $create, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    
        
    if ($stmt ->execute()) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Unable to create record";
    }
    

?>
```

Comment: Some typos in the variable names. You use `$dMobile` but don't create it, but you do create `$bMobile` twice, same for `$dEmail` and `$dPhone`. You use `$create` too, and I don't see where that comes from. You have a parameter `:id` but don't assign a value to it, which is probably more of the problem. You assign a value to `:create`, but that doesn't appear in the query. You can probably enable error-trapping and get some idea of these errors.

Comment: Thanks for catching those.  Good point on the error-trapping, I thought I had that, but now see it is only for my connection statement, which is working.